# .NET How to Send WebRequest on Specified IP address in same domain

Tags: .net, ssl, https, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have a problem. Whenever I'm sending WebRequest to https://myaddress.com, it resolves to the wrong IP address (this domain has several IP adresses). How can I specify IP address, which I want to send the WebRequest to?

```
var uri = new Uri(url);
var changedUrl = "{0}://{1}:{2}{3}".FormatWith(uri.Scheme, ipWithPort.Ip, ipWithPort.Port, uri.PathAndQuery);
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(changedUrl);
webRequest.Host = uri.Authority;
```

If uri scheme - **http** is work fine, but **https** raise certificate validation fail:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((s, ce, ch, ssl) => 
{
     return ssl == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
});
```

ssl is SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors in this case.
Note: Always return true is not solution.

Dynamically edit Host file? Maybe its solution?

Comment: HTTP vs HTTPS will not affect DNS resolution for a domain, you will get the same record for myaddress.com in both cases..

Comment: Accessing a domain via it's IP address will always generate SSL errors if  the certificate used is for the domain is bound to the domain name, to avoid this you need to handle the error, ensuring the certificate that was served is what you expect.

Comment: Understood. But how to handle this certificate? can you attach an example? Is there any other way to handle https on certain ip-address?

Comment: The correct way would be to create a DNS record for a sub-domain pointing to the correct IP, generate a certificate, configure web the server and call that over HTTPs.

Comment: But how works webrequest with url(not ip-address)? He always finds a working ip-address, by searching, if i pass https url, but it does so for a long time (near 3 min timeout). Why we can't forced to say ip-address to go?